# Doctrine association just fill 1 of 2 tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm still taking the code behind a developer leaving without giving any manual.
I'd like to know if it's possible to say to doctrine not to persist data in persist data in the 2 tables.

2 tables :

- rule => store all elements of rules (name, port, service, source address, status, etc...)
- status => store status of rule (Asked, In production, Rejected)

Rule entity :

```
/**
    *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="status", inversedBy="statuses", cascade={"persist"})
    *@ORM\JoinColumn("name="status_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
    */
    private $status
```

status entity:

```
      /**
        *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="rule", mappedBy="status")
         */
        private $statuses
```

Tables:

```
----------                      ---------
 Rule                              Status
----------                       ---------- 
 ID                               ID
 Name                             Name
 Status_Id                        Colour
 SourcePort                      ----------
 DestinationPort
 Protocol
 ----------
```

the problem is that each time i try to save a new rule, doctrine tries to persist the id of status_in_rule_id in table status like status_id.

I'd like to know if there's a way to telle doctrine to only save the status_id in rule tble without trying to persist anything in status table

RuleController:

```
    $namespace = 'FwBundle';
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager($this->getUser()->getUserService()->getName());

    $repositoryFw = $em->getRepository($namespace.':Fw');   
    $repositoryStatus = $em->getRepository($namespace.':Status');
    $liste_fws = $repositoryFw->myFindVisible();

    $rule = new rule();
    $form = $this->createForm(RuleType::class, $rule,array('fw'=>$id));

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $fw = $repositoryFw->findOneById($id);
        $status = $repositoryStatus->findOneByShortName('startvalue');
        $rule->setStatus($status);
        $em->persist($rule);
        $em->flush();
```

Dump Message:

```
status {#1509 ▼
  -id: 1
  -name: "just posted by customer"
  -shortName: "startvalue"
  -colour: "blue"
  -statuses: PersistentCollection {#1511 ▼
    -snapshot: []
    -owner: status {#1509}
    -association: array:15 [ …15]
    -em: EntityManager {#449 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "status"
    -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#463 …}
    -isDirty: false
    #collection: ArrayCollection {#1512 ▶}
    #initialized: false
  }
}
```

Comment: If you set an already-existing `Status` entity on your `Rule` entity, it won't persist a brand new Status, it will use the id of your existing Status entity.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'm sorry, but what do you mean by set an already existing status ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's a new instance of a `Status` entity.  You'll either want to load the `Status` entity yourself

`$status = $entityManager->getRepository(Status::class)->find($id);`

and set it in `Rule`

`$rule->setStatus($status)`

or make sure you're using the `Status` associated with the current `Rule` you're editing.  Remember, you're working with objects and not values.  So `$rule->setStatus(1);` isn't valid. Also check to make sure you're

`$entityManager->persist($rule);`

Comment: i already done that, but it didn't work i just post the controller in the edit

Comment: Your code looks proper and it's still inserting a new row in your `Status` table??   I'd probably make sure `$status` contains a value.  You can start by adding `dump($status)` and check the Developer bar at the bottom of your browser.    Also, `tail -f` your query log and see if you can find anything in there.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i added the dump message to the edit. It finds the good status and try to persist it in status table

Comment: What's the `statuses` relationship supposed to be used for?  It appears to be a self-referencing oneToMany?  I believe that's where your `INSERT` is coming from.   Comment out that annotation so Doctrine ignores it and test again.

Comment: statuses is useless, you're right, i suppressed it, but still get the INSERT

Comment: `$ php bin/console cache:clear`  just to make sure Doctrine doesn't have anything cached for that definition.  I'm at a total loss without seeing all the code.  Check for any listeners/subscribers.  Something is detached.  Possibly work around it with `$em->merge($status)`.   I have no other suggestions.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, but i had some problem thse lasts weeks and time ran fast. I tried to clear cache but didn't solve my problem. I'll post all the code soon